# J2ME Bluetooth service registry when app is off

Tags: java-me, bluetooth

S40 doesnt allow an app to run in the background so the only way that I can know if the phone has a given BT service is to have the app running

Is it possible to register a service to the Bluetooth registry such that it is visible even when the app is off?